# is there any way we can define the types for the addEventListener and classList in a react typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, addeventlistener

In our project(React with typescript) we are using the below code to add and manipulate the underline for the tabs in navigation bar.

```
public componentDidMount() {
        const tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, (tab: EventListener) => {
            tab.addEventListener("click", setActiveClass);
        });

        const setActiveClass = (event: any) => {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, (tab: any) => {
                tab.classList.remove("active");
            });
            event.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
        };
    }.
```

The typescript is throwing following errors :
"[ts] Property 'addEventListener' does not exist on type 'EventListener'" and 
"[tslint] Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type. (no-any)"

I would like to add appropriate types instead of using "any" in the code. I would also don't want to relax the tslint rule for "any"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `call` is inherently not type safe. The definition of call will basically erase any function type information as it uses `any`:

```
call(this: Function, thisArg: any, ...argArray: any[]): any;
```

If you call `forEach` as a normal instance function the type of the parameter to the arrow function will be correctly inferred:

```
tabs.forEach(tab => {
    tab.addEventListener("click", setActiveClass);
});

const setActiveClass = (event: Event) => {
    tabs.forEach(tab => {
        tab.classList.remove("active");
    });
    if(event.currentTarget != null){
        (event.currentTarget as Element).classList.add("active");
    }
};
```